# PM2 in cluster mode, don't start after reboot until I remove the folder

Tags: node.js, pm2

I'm new in NodeJS but for some reasons I need to use this app:
https://github.com/ZitRos/save-analytics-from-content-blockers

I've cloned the repository, installed the required modules using npm install, and I'm able to run the app using the command npm start.

Because I need to start the app on boot and I want to use it in multiple threads, I've installed and configured PM2 for that, and I'm using this ecosystem.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name: 'Analytics Proxy',
    script: './src/api.js',
    cwd: '/server/proyects/analytics_proxy/',

    // Options reference: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/
    interpreter_args: '-r esm',
    instances: 1,
    exec_mode: 'cluster',
    autorestart: true,
    watch: true,
    max_memory_restart: '256M',
    env: {
      NODE_ENV: 'production'
    },
  }],
};
```

At first attemp the cluster was running without problem even with 4 instances, but after reboot I've noticed that the cluster wont boot again. After looking into the logs I've seen that there's an error finding the ESM module:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'esm'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at Module._preloadModules (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:12)
    at preloadModules (internal/bootstrap/node.js:602:7)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:273:9)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
```

I've tried to install the module globally and doesn't fix the problem, but anyway is strange because in Fork mode it start without problem even after reboot and if I remove the entire /root.pm2/ folder then it works again in cluster mode.

Also If I use the pm2 update command, sometimes it works again.
[PM2 Update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVqZa.png)

Anyone knows how I can solve this problem?.

Best regards, and thanks!

Comment: Having exactly the same issue with a node Express app that uses esm. There's a related issue on GitHub: https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/4583

Comment: Thanks!!, I'll take a look.